# How to dynamically filter based on different column in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have two columns site and Profit catgeory.
Site --> A, B, C
Profit Category --> 1,2,3 [ It will be calculated dynamically, when data changes]

Data:

[image: Data]

I want to filter site based on profit category.

Workbook:

[image: Workbook]

If I select Site A in filter option, it hsould display all the sites which is in same Profit category as Site A. If Site A falls under Profit Category 1 means all Sites wchich falls under Profit Catgeory 1 should be dispalyed.

I am struck with this. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display a **parameter** control instead of a *filter* control.

Parameters are used to hold the (single) response from the user for making a choice. You can reference parameters in many places, including calculated fields. You can then use calculated fields as a filter.

You can combine these features in different ways. In your case, I suggest creating a parameter based on the Site field. Showing the parameter control and allowing the user to select a site. Then building a boolean calculated field to determine whether a record should be included in the analysis or not based on the selected site and the data values in the current record.

Filter on that calculated field and you should be able to get the effect you  described.